# Photoshop scripting updates

Tags: photoshop-scripting

Last year, I've heard, that the Action manager won't be supported in newer versions of Photoshop (like q3 2022 or something like that).

Since then, I didn't keep up with the scripting side whatsoever, and now I'd like to ask: is this still true? Will Action manager not be supported? Are there good alternatives now, or will some good alternatives come out soon?

No, I can't use the provided scripting API, as it's painfully slow.

Comment: Hi, not actions, ActionManager code. This includes `ActionDescriptor`, `ActionReference`, etc. Programming with action ids and similar.

Comment: Its not actually called a DOM that kind of naming convention is reserved for webpages. Mainly because ist more than a document model ita a application model. The scripting api is just a scripting api. Yeah probably they will kill the api as it currentky stands.

Comment: I don't really care about the scripting API, as the speed is a pain. I was asking regarding the low level ActionManager stuff, as it's really fast, but hard to work with, and I've heard some changes (or full deprecation) are coming to it.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh they are dependent on eachother. SO most probably yes. WHen this happens is not known. If they replace this with anything is also not known.

Comment: so as it stands, it will (might) be removed, but nothing exists now to replace it? Meaning if I want to do some scripting now, I have to use the low level ugly fast, but it won't be usable in near future versions? No other alternatives? And thanks

Comment: Thats the info we have. Same applies to everything I have ever done. But theres not enough info to draw any conclusions. They will replace it with something if its fast or even usable by us is unknown

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to confirm that this is what the situation currently is, as I wasn't able to find any updates. Good day to you